# Issue importing Google AI Platform Python Library

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-ai-platform

I'm trying to import the Google Cloud AI Platform python library into a jupyter notebook in python 3.9, but I get the error below. The code that I'm running is:

```
from google.cloud.aiplatform import gapic as aip
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-d3786173dd52> in <module>
----> 1 from google.cloud.aiplatform import gapic as aip
      2 
      3 # aiplatform.init(project=PROJECT_ID, location=REGION, staging_bucket=BUCKET_NAME)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/__init__.py in <module>
     20 
     21 from google.cloud.aiplatform import initializer
---> 22 from google.cloud.aiplatform.datasets import (
     23     ImageDataset,
     24     TabularDataset,

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/datasets/__init__.py in <module>
     17 
     18 from google.cloud.aiplatform.datasets.dataset import _Dataset
---> 19 from google.cloud.aiplatform.datasets.tabular_dataset import TabularDataset
     20 from google.cloud.aiplatform.datasets.time_series_dataset import TimeSeriesDataset
     21 from google.cloud.aiplatform.datasets.image_dataset import ImageDataset

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/datasets/tabular_dataset.py in <module>
     23 from google.auth import credentials as auth_credentials
     24 
---> 25 from google.cloud import bigquery
     26 from google.cloud import storage
     27 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/__init__.py in <module>
     33 __version__ = bigquery_version.__version__
     34 
---> 35 from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client
     36 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import AccessEntry
     37 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import Dataset

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py in <module>
     65 from google.cloud.bigquery._helpers import _verify_job_config_type
     66 from google.cloud.bigquery._http import Connection
---> 67 from google.cloud.bigquery import _pandas_helpers
     68 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import Dataset
     69 from google.cloud.bigquery.dataset import DatasetListItem

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py in <module>
    108     # When modifying it be sure to update it there as well.
    109     BQ_TO_ARROW_SCALARS = {
--> 110         "BOOL": pyarrow.bool_,
    111         "BOOLEAN": pyarrow.bool_,
    112         "BYTES": pyarrow.binary,

AttributeError: module 'pyarrow' has no attribute 'bool_'
```

I've also tried running:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform
```

But this results in the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-38c2222adbb6> in <module>
----> 1 import pyarrow.lib as _lib

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/serialization.pxi in init pyarrow.lib()

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyarrow/serialization.pxi in pyarrow.lib.SerializationContext.__init__()

AttributeError: module 'cloudpickle' has no attribute 'dumps'
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by uninstalling cloudpickle with

```
pip uninstall cloudpickle
```

and then reinstalling cloudpickle

```
pip install cloudpickle
```

This resolved the issue with pyarrow too.